# Trying to screen scrapy with selenium and BS. Getting a weird error that doesn't seem logical at all

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to grab some data from this link.

https://www.congress.gov/members?q={%22congress%22:%22115%22}&pageSize=250&page=

Here is the code that I am testing.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Utility/chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

url = 'https://www.congress.gov/members?q={%22congress%22:%22115%22}&pageSize=250&page='
browser.get(url)

time.sleep(10) # wait page open complete

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'expanded'})
for div in data:
    links = div.findAll('a')
    for a in links:
        print(a['href'])
```

I keep getting this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 6, in <module>
    forest.fit(X_train, y_train)

NameError: name 'X_train' is not defined
```

I don't see anything, whatsoever, related to any kind of 'X_train'.

Ultimately, I am trying to get a CSV file with this:

```
MEMBER
1. Representative Abraham, Ralph Lee
Abraham, Ralph Lee
State: Louisiana District: 5 Party: Republican Served:
House: 2015-Present

MEMBER
2. Representative Adams, Alma S.
Adams, Alma S.
State: North Carolina District: 12 Party: Democratic Served:
House: 2014-Present

MEMBER
3. Representative Aderholt, Robert B.
Aderholt, Robert B.
State: Alabama District: 4 Party: Republican Served:
House: 1997-Present
```

I am using Spyder 3.6.  Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use `X_train` variable without declaration somewhere in your code.

I've tested your code sample and it worked as expected with a single tweak by replacing `div` with `li` in the following line:

    data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'expanded'})

Comment: I just made that same change on my side.  I am still getting the same error.  It almost seems like something is jammed up in memory, but I can't figure out what it is.  I just created a new instance of Sypder and started a new node...I am still getting this error, which seems to be completely unrelated to anything at all...

Comment: OK, I uninstalled and then reinstalled Selenium.  Now everything works fine.